# object object return by AJAX/jQuery on alert box after running SQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, jquery

Can someone please help? Here is my jQuery. The scenario is this, I have a table where it has a button on with every `<td>`.If you click that button a modal window will appear with a confirmation button on it with yes or no. If the user clicks yes (`#confirm_cancel`), this will save in the database then show an alert box wherein it tells the users that the update was successful. The problem is this, it properly executes my SQL and saves to the database but I get an alert box on error function that says `[object object]`.

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
include("php/openDB.php"); 

echo '<table border="2" id="tableGuestList">';
echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Guest ID</td>';
    echo '<td>Room No:</td>';
    echo '<td>First Name</td>';
    echo '<td>Last Name</td>';
    echo '<td>Checkin</td> ';
    echo '<td>checkout</td>';
    echo '<td>Status</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT gi.guest_id, gi.fname, gi.lname, bk.checkin, bk.checkout, bk.transacstatus, bk.reserved_id "
    ."FROM tbl_guestinfo gi, tbl_bookings bk "
    ."where gi.guest_id = bk.guest_id "
    ."AND bk.transacstatus = 'booked'");

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $guest_id = $rows[0];

        $fname = $rows[1];
        $lname = $rows[2];
        $checkin = $rows[3];
        $checkout = $rows[4];
        $transacstatus = $rows[5];
        $reservedid = $rows[6];


        echo '<tr id="'.$rows[0].'" class="bookedClass">';
        echo '<td>'.$guest_id.'</td>';
        echo '<td> room number kaara</td>';
        echo '<td> '.$fname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$lname.'</td>';
        echo '<td> '.$checkin.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$checkout.'</td>';
        echo '<td> '.$transacstatus.'</td>';

        echo '<td style="display:none"> '.$reservedid.'</td>';

        echo '<td> <input type = "submit" value = "Cancel Booking" name ="cancel_booking" /></td>';

        echo '<td> <input type = "submit" value = "Check in" name ="check_in" /></td>';

        //echo '<td> <input type = "submit" value = "Check Out" name ="Check_Out" /></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);

    echo '</table>';

    include("php/closeDB.php");
?>
```

this is my jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var selGuest;
    $('#tableGuestList .bookedClass').click(function(){
        selGuest = $(this).find("td").eq(7).text();
        selGuest = parseInt(selGuest)
        $('#confirmDialog').fadeIn('slow');
    });

    $('#confirm_cancel').click(function() {
        var canceldata_json = {
            'selGuest': selGuest,
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: canceldata_json,
            url: "./php/cancelBooking.php",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("guest information updated")
                $('#confirmDialog').fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function(msg){
                alert(msg)
            }
        });
    });

    $('#cancel_cancel').click(function() {
        $('#confirmDialog').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

and here is my PHP code being called by the AJAX

```
<?php

// get data
$selGuest = $_POST["selGuest"];

include("openDB.php");

$insertintoCanceled = "insert into tbl_canceled "
        ."reserved_id, `guest_id`,`checkin`, `checkout`, `type_id`, `numAdults`, `numChildren`, `transacstatus`, `amountDue`"
        ."("
        ."SELECT * FROM `tbl_bookings` where `reserved_id` =" .$selGuest
        .")";
if(!mysql_query($insertintoCanceled, $con))//if it fails
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error() . "\n");//show the mysql error
}
include("closeDB.php");
?>
```

Comment: BUT when I do this transfer it to another click function it worked. The  $('#confirm_cancel') and  $('#cancel_cancel') button are inside that modal window that I made after clicking the $('#tableGuestList .bookedClass')

Comment: $('#tableGuestList .bookedClass').click(function(){ var canceldata_json = {
            'selGuest': selGuest,
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: canceldata_json,
            url: "./php/cancelBooking.php",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert("guest information updated")
                $('#confirmDialog').fadeOut('slow');
            },
            error: function(msg){
                alert(msg)
            }
        });
});

Comment: Here's what I get from firebug. Object {readyState=0, status=0, statustext = "erro"}error (an empty string)

Actually it just flashes in my screen. The alert pop up then I dont even click the ok button and it closes... any help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by `alert(msg)`. `msg` may be an object, and the actual data you want is one of its property values. Try setting a breakpoint within Chrome dev tools or Firebug within the error function and inspecting what value `msg` contains. It may be as simple as using  `alert(msg.d)` instead.

Comment: thank you. I did try the breakpoint but I dont know what I want to know. I mean what I need to see or how.. please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your "error:function(msg)" callback function isn't using the right arguments.

I would suggest:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); //Check with Chrome or FF to see all these objects and decide what you want to display
    alert('Error! '+textStatus);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also, check your PHP error logs to see if it does what you intend it to do.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did try this solution of yours and its just change the errors. The problem is that I had successfully updated my table in my database but why its still in error popping out. where I believe that it should be on the success since it updated correctly. By the way I tested my sql statement and its working fine. can you help me on this please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just want the "upload successful" message.

I think it is best to use dataType as JSON (response from the server in JSON format).
Try this in your AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: canceldata_json,
    dataType:'json',
    url: "./php/cancelBooking.php",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg)
        $('#confirmDialog').fadeOut('slow');
    },
    error:function(msg){
        alert(msg)
    }
});
```

and ur php function

```
<?php

// get data
$selGuest = $_POST["selGuest"];

include("openDB.php");

$insertintoCanceled = "insert into tbl_canceled "
    ."reserved_id, `guest_id`,`checkin`, `checkout`, `type_id`, `numAdults`,        `numChildren`, `transacstatus`, `amountDue`"
."("
."SELECT * FROM `tbl_bookings` where `reserved_id` =" .$selGuest
.")";
if(!mysql_query($insertintoCanceled, $con))//if it fails
{
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Error')) //error msg goes here
die('Error: ' . mysql_error() . "\n");//show the mysql error

}
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Successfully updated')) //success msg goes here
include("closeDB.php");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try this but still getting the error where it should be success coz I successfully update my database.